# String format using UWP and x:Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Does anyone know how to format a date when using x:Bind in a UWP Windows 10 app?

I have a TextBlock that is bound (x:Bind) to a DateTime property on my ViewModel which is read from SQL. I want to format the output to "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm (ddd)". Is there a simple way of doing this?

The default format is "dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss" which I presume is coming from a default. Could this be replaced maybe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a `StringFormatConverter` (check if you maybe use some library, which already includes it, e.g. the [UWP Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/converters) (thanks, @maxp) or the older [Cimbalino Toolkit](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Toolkit%20(WP8)/Converters/StringFormatConverter.cs)):

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (parameter == null)
            return value;

        return string.Format((string)parameter, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

add it to your page resource

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:StringFormatConverter x:Key="StringFormatConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

and use it like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Text, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:dd/MM/yyy HH\\\\:mm (ddd)}'}" />
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much sibbl. Works a treat.

Comment: I've just noticed this is also part of the UWP Toolkit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/converters

Answer (score 12):

you can use

```
{x:Bind ViewModel.DateTimeProperty.ToString("....")}
```

Comment: You sure can, as long as you target Creators Update

Comment: In my case is not working because the compiler interprets that I'm calling to the ToString(IFormatProvider) overload, so I'd to call the (string, IFormatParameter) overload like this: {x:Bind ViewModel.DateTimeProperty.ToString('...', {x:Null})}

Comment: The comment of @joseangelmt should be the answer to save people a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Formated DateTime]

[Function binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings) is much better approach than classic Converter:

```xml
 <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DateTimeToString(MyDateTime,'dd/MM/yyy HH\\\\:mm (ddd)')}" />
```

Code behind (it could be placed in separate class):

```cs
//"Converter"
public string DateTimeToString(DateTime dateTime, string format) => dateTime.ToString(format);

public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

### Why is it better than classic converter?

- Shorter -> no boil plait code
- Strongly typed -> Detects exceptions in build time.

Answer (score 2):

similar to the code behind

```
xmlns:globalization="using:System.Globalization"
...

{x:Bind ViewModel.DateTimeProperty.ToString('dd/MM/yyy HH:mm (ddd)', globalization:DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)}

...
```