# Data binding part of string in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to achieve the following

```
<controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="200"
               Height="200"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Source="/Assets/DemoImages/123_DemoImage.jpg"
               Stretch="Uniform" />
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
```

Given the itemsource of

```
<controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PropertySearchList}"
```

and PropertySearchList is a

```
List<ToLetProperty> PropertySearchList
```

with the ToLetProperty class having a string property of FrontImage (and other properties)

for example :

```
Source="/Assets/DemoImages/{ToLetProperty.FrontImage}"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String format using UWP and x:Bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026332/string-format-using-uwp-and-xbind)

Comment: Easiest way is write a converter passing the image name and convert that to Full `URI` to `Source`

Comment: tried this ? `<DataTemplate  x:DataType="namespace:ToLetProperty"> ..... <Image source="FrontImage" ...> </DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use `{x:Bind}` with data templates, we must indicate the type being bound to by setting an `x:DataType` value. We can set the base class type to it.

In the `Image` control, we can use set `FrontImage` property to the Source by the `x:Bind`.

For example:

```
<controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PropertySearchList}" >
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ToLetProperty">
            <Image Width="200" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{x:Bind FrontImage}" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Carousel>
```

By the way, I suggest you use the [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7) to instead of `List`. It represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks! That’s perfect 